# Wordpress - show div on page if first time logging in

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I’m a little new to Wordpress and am trying to work out via PHP in premade page (not posts) how I can show a div if it’s the users first time logging in (just some basic instructions).

I see this for the functions.php file but I’m trying to add this into a custom made dashboard page:

```
function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {
    $new_user = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', true);
    if ($new_user) {
        update_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', '0');

        // do something for first login.. e.g., send a custom email
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create  `_new_user` meta after user register:

```
add_action('user_register', 'mobius2000_54376815_add_user_meta');      
function mobius2000_54376815_add_user_meta($user_id) {    
  add_user_meta($user_id, '_new_user', 1); 
}
```

Then you can check in your dashboard function:

```
function mobius2000_54376815_custom_dashboard() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
  $new_user = get_user_meta(user_id, '_new_user', true);
  if($new_user == 1) { // first login 
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_new_user', 0); 
    // do action
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Sky, thanks so much for the reply... So does all of that go into the functions.php file? If so, how would the if{ part look? Would it be if...{ echo ‘<div>show this</div>’;